# Buddypress login/register error with pop-up

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site, using buddypress. I want the user to be able to login and register for the site without using the wordpress login page. For this i am using a plugin, Clean Login to take input in the form through a pop up. It takes the imput but doesnt save or log the user in. 
Here is the website:
bublic.eu

Now I do not understand why does it not work. I've searched on google and tried various plugins. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code i ve added to the header.php file to create buttons and the pop up and take input on the form from the user:

//for login/register

```
    <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
                <div class="buttons-right">
                    <a href="#loginbox" class="login fancybox">LOG IN</a>
                    <a href="#register" class="signup fancybox">SIGN UP</a>
                </div>
                <div id="loginbox" style="display:none">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[clean-login]'); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="register" style="display:none">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[clean-login-register]'); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="forgot_pwd" style="display: none">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[clean-login-restore]'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="buttons-right">
                    <a href="/?clean_login_action=logout" class="logout">LOG OUT</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: You have not shown any detail about what your issue is.  What code you have tried, what results you get.  Instead, it seems like you are asking SO folks to do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the code to be checked.